# Domain classes not visible to Data layer (Application context class )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

To make data-layer be aware of my domain classes, I've added a reference between the two class libraries, `HMSContext` (i.e., data-layer) and `Hms.Entities` (i.e., domain-classes).

Following is code from `HMS.Entities`:

```
namespace HMS.Entities
{
    class Accomodation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int AccomodationPackageID { get; set; }
        public AccomodationPackage AccomodationPackage { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code from `HMSContext.cs`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace HMS.Data
{
    public class HMSContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Accomodation> Accomodations { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I've added a reference between these two .dlls. A snapshot showing this is attached [here](https://pasteboard.co/jdHtRbCpHIH5.png). For some reason, `HRMContext.cs` is not reading `HMS.Entities` despite added reference. Am I missing anything? Can someone please shed light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for starters, you are missing `using HMS.Entities`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `using System.Data.Entity;` where it is not related to your project structure. So add `HMS.Entities` too.

Any time you have such a problem, try using the full namespace and check if it is correct or not.

Note that you also have **refactoring** capabilities too. You can use ( Ctrl + . ) and Visual Studio helps you to use the correct namespace.

Your code has to be like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using HMS.Entities;

namespace HMS.Data
{
    public class HMSContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Accomodation> Accomodations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And for the Entity class you should use `public` keyword:

```
namespace HMS.Entities
{
    public class Accomodation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int AccomodationPackageID { get; set; }
        public AccomodationPackage AccomodationPackage { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: while typing using HMS.Entities [this](https://pasteboard.co/mgd8UYX6Pku2.png) error is showing up

Comment: @Oxin you forgot `public` keyword.

Comment: btw, without `using System.Data.Entity`, how will `HMSContext` inherit from `DbContext`?

Comment: True that. I added `public`  keyword to `Accomodation` class and problem has resolved. Thank You Sir.

Comment: @Oxin just keep `using System.Data.Entity` and add your entity's namespace.